# Posting file name and file contents to remote server via curl command

Tags: bash, embedded, curl

I'm trying to write a bash script that would post the name and content of a local file to a remote server via `curl`.

Local file name has the following format:

```
/tmp/DeviceID-Date.txt
```

For eg. `178-20171105.txt`.

Remote server: http://myserver.com/insert.php

The remote `insert.php` script part would then explode the `$_POST['filename']` to extract **DeviceID** and **Date**, and get the contents of the file through `$_POST['filedata']` to store all this info in the server's database (this part I got covered already).

Is that possible?

**Note**:  this is a small text file (max 6 KB). I tried `--upload-file` and got "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed".

Comment: If you want to ensure that the file contents are not disturbed you might want to take a different approach and use curl's `--upload-file` option to send the content (FYI it uses PUT) and pass the filename in a header (e.g. `--header 'filename: DeviceID-Date.txt'`).

Comment: Try `curl -F "file=@/tmp/DeviceID-Date.txt;filename=DeviceID-Date.txt" url`. But your server side script must accept content-type `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: @BLayer tried both your suggestions and got `curl: (27) PRNG seeding failed`

Comment: Alternatively use `curl -F "filedata=</tmp/DeviceID-Date.txt" -F "filename=DeviceID-Date.txt" url`. This will convert contents of the file to simple text in a text field but obviously won't work with binary files.

Comment: I split them and still got the same error `curl: (27) PRNG seeding failed`. I wonder why.

Comment: I've never seen that error. You should google it. Are you using an up-to-date version of curl? (`curl --version`)